# No read access to ProfileId for a User over the REST API

Tags: rest-api, profile, user

We've been looking up `ProfileId` from a given user that has OAuth-ed already. Normally they're returning the Id correctly when we call this:

> /services/data/v28.0/sobjects/User/THEIR_USER_ID

However, for one user, we noticed the `ProfileId` is not readable.

When calling describe on the User object, it does not return a field with the name `ProfileId`.

> /services/data/v28.0/sobjects/User/describe

This made me believe that Read permission for the `ProfileId` field was disabled so I tried changing the User field read permissions for one of our profiles. Then I saw the following:

> Note that on the User object, field-level security is only supported for custom fields, not standard fields.

How has someone disabled read access to the `ProfileId`? I want to follow some steps to allow me to reproduce this on our SFDC Edition.

I read the [User API docs](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm#ProfileId) for `ProfileId` and noticed that it used to be called `RoleId`. However this is also not present in the `describe` response.

Steps to edit the profile's User field permissions:

> Setup -> Manage Users -> Profiles -> Selected one of our profiles -> Scrolled down to the section "Field-Level Security" -> Selected [View] for User -> The message is right under the profile's name

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I have been using is to use the AccessToken returned OAuth token to call make a SOAP API call to the [getUserInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_getuserinfo.htm).

Kind of a bummer that a second web-service call is needed, but it seems to do the trick.